# How do I define unique constraint in hibernate for this situation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, hibernate-mapping

Destination and DestinationAlias at database level look like this:

[image: DestinationAlias and Destination]

In DestinationAlias, (idDestination, alias) is unique.

POJO for DestinationAlias:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DESTINATIONALIAS",
uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"IDDESTINATION", "ALIAS"}) }
        )
public final class DestinationAlias {

// ..

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="IDDESTINATION", nullable=false)
    public Destination getMainCity() {
        return mainCity;
    }
}
```

Should the unique constraint be IDDESTINATION or "MAINCITY" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique constraint annotation expects a list of column names. So in your case, no, it should not be 'MAINCITY'. Also note thats its best practice to use the same case as your actual database fields, as some databases are case sensitive. So your code should be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DestinationAlias", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "idDestination", "alias" }) })
public final class DestinationAlias {
    // ....
}
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html